# DB2: Unable to set pagesize while creating a database

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to create a DB2 database with the following command

```
CREATE DATABASE rpedb1 AUTOMATIC STORAGE Yes
USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US COLLATE
USING SYSTEM PAGESIZE 16384;
```

But while creating getting an error message as

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "16384;" was found following "PAGESIZE".
Expected tokens may include:  "<unsigned-short-number>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

I have tried all the possible combinations including 1GB,2GB,etc... and also using K letter for thousand. What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: DB2 on i (AS400) or DB2 LUW? Which version?

Comment: How do you run the statement? Looks like the semicolon is not expected.

Comment: Hello Data_henrik/ Mustaccio, I'm using DB2_ESE_v10.1-FP4 on Windows 2012 R2 machine.I run this statement via CLI mode

Comment: What's "CLI mode"? Copy and paste the exact command (including the CLP invocation if you run the command interactively).

Comment: CLI mode means command mode and i have removed the pagesize which has been mentioned.Now the issue has been resolved.Thank you and sorry for the delay